# How to draw K1,3 and C5 as a cartesian product?

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

I've already drawn a complete bipartite graph with 1 vertex in the 'X' set and 3 vertices in the 'Y' set, but how do I fit the C5 in that graph? I can't picture it. Then how do I find the maximum independent set of that graph, clique number, chromatic number, and the minimum coloring?

Answer (score 1):

It's not exactly clear what you are asking. Are you trying to write $K_{1,3}, C_5,$ and/or $K_{1,3} + C_5$ as the Cartesian product of two graphs? You've shown that it can be done for $K_{1,3}$ but it can be shown that you can't do it for $C_5$ or $K_{1,3} + C_5$.

Are you sure that you don't mean to draw the Cartesian product of $K_{1,3}$ and $C_5$? If this is the case, then the easiest way to draw this is by considering $K_{1,3}$ and drawing a copy of $C_5$ for each vertex in $K_{1,3}$. Then, for each adjacent pair of vertices in $K_{1,3}$, you have the associated copies of $C_5$ in your Cartesian product; connect the corresponding vertices in those copies of $C_5$.

You get the following drawing as a result. (I interpreted $K_{1,3}$ as the star $S_3$.)
[image]